# I need to use a loop in R but don't know where to start

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a calculation that I have to perform for 23 people (they have varying number of rows allocated to each person so difficult to do in excel.  What I'd like to do is take the total time each person took to complete a test and divide it into 5 time categories (20%) so that I can look at their reaction time in more detail.

I will just do this by hand but it will take quite a while because they have 8 sets of data each.  I'm hoping someone can show me the best way to use a loop or automate this process even just a little. I have tried to understand the examples but I'm afraid I don't have the skill.  So by hand I would do it like I have below where I just filter by each subject.
I started by selecting the relevant columns, then filtered by subject so that I could calculate the time they started and the time they finished and used that to create a variable (testDuration) that could be used to create the 20% proportions of RTs that I'm after.  I have no idea how to get the individual subjects' test start, end, duration and timeBin sizes to appear in one column.  Any help very gratefully received.

```
Subj1 <- rtTrialsYA_s1 %>%
  select(Subject, RetRating.OnsetTime, RetRating.RT, RetRating.RTTime) %>%
  filter(Subject==1) %>%
  summarise(
    testStart =
min(RetRating.OnsetTime),
    testEnd = max(RetRating.RTTime)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    testDuration = testEnd - testStart,
    timeBin =
testDuration/5
  )

Subj2 <- rtTrialsYA_s1 %>%
  select(Subject, RetRating.OnsetTime, RetRating.RT, RetRating.RTTime) %>%
  filter(Subject==2) %>%
  summarise(
    testStart =
min(RetRating.OnsetTime),
    testEnd = max(RetRating.RTTime)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    testDuration = testEnd - testStart,
    timeBin =
testDuration/5
  )
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about the data structure and desired output. Can you give an example of what you would like the looped output to look like?

Comment: Please use ``dput(rtTrialsYA_s1)`` to show us what your data looks like. Thank you.

Comment: Try replacing the "filter" line with "group_by(Subject)". You should get one data.frame with the summary stats for each subject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive that I understand your code, but this function can be called for any Subject value and then return the output:

```
myfunction <- function(subjectNumber){
  Subj <- rtTrialsYA_s1 %>% 
    select(Subject, RetRating.OnsetTime, RetRating.RT, RetRating.RTTime) %>% 
    filter(Subject==subjectNumber) %>% 
    summarise(testStart = min(RetRating.OnsetTime), testEnd = max(RetRating.RTTime)) %>% 
    mutate(testDuration = testEnd -testStart) %>% 
    mutate(timeBin = testDuration/5)
  return(Subj)
}

Subj1 <- myfunction(1)
Subj2 <- myfunction(2)
```

To loop through this, I'll need to know what your data and the desired output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing one piece and that is simply `dplyr::group_by`.

You can use it as follows to break your dataset  into groups, each containing the observations belonging to only one subject, and then summarise on those groups with whatever it is you want to analyze.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- rtTrialsYA_s1 %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  summarise(
    testStart = min(RetRating.OnsetTime),
    testEnd = max(RetRating.RTTime),
    testDuration = testEnd - testStart,
    timeBin = testDuration/5,
    .groups = "drop"
  )
```

There is no need to do separate `mutate` calls in your code, btw. Also, you can continue to do column calculations right within `summarise`, as long as the result vectors have the same length as your aggregated columns.
And since `summarise` retains only the grouping columns and whatever you are defining, there is no real need to do a select statement before, either.

// update
You say you need all your calculated columns to appear within one single column. For that you can use `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Using the `df` we calculated above:

```
library(tidyr)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Subject)
```

Above will take all columns, except `Subject` and pivot them into two columns, one containing the former col name and one containing the former value.